Why the solution to this PDE, provided by DSolve, does not solve the PDE? (How to correctly use DSolve for such equations?)
This is a question about the correct way to use DSolve.
In the image below, I wrote a partial differential equation.
I asked Mathematica to solve it, and you can see the suggested solution.

Plugging this solution back to the LHS of the PDE does not yield zero, however, which is confusing since it must be zero by definition. Am I using this PDE solver wrong?

pde = D[y[x, t], t] - D[D[y[x, t], x], x] - D[x y[x, t], x] == 0;
soln = DSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi]}, y[x, t], {x, t}, 
  Assumptions -> t > 0]


Updates: (1) I made sure that the calculation has run on a clean kernel, and that I have not defined y[x,t] by mistake before using DSolve.
(2) Removing the Assumption leads to a similar result, with a clause saying "if Re[t]>-1/2".

I do not get the same result as you; DSolve returns the input. Please run your code again in a fresh kernel, and specify which version of Mathematica you're using. From your code, I suspect you have defined y[x, t] before running DSolve, hence the result doesn't make sense.

The boundary condition is very unusual , where does it come from?

For the second derivative, you can do D[y[x, t], {x, 2}]. (That's not a solution, just a comment.) Do you have any reason to believe that Mathematica can deal with delta-function initial conditions?

@Domen     Thanks. I ran the calculation on a fresh kernel, using the code that you add to my question above (and nothing else, so definitely not defining y[x,t] before this calculation). Now I am getting: y[x,t]->e^{t-(1+t)^2x^2/(2+4t)}/sqrt{2 Pi (1+2t)}.  It's very puzzling!
I am using Mathematica 12.2 .
What do you think is going on here?

@March     Thanks. I used your version of the second derivative and changed the delta-function into a Gaussian. I am getting again a wrong answer, only slightly different from the previous case. I updated my question above.

@UlrichNeumann     I have a Gaussian initial condition.

With Mathematica 14.0 on Windows, DSolve returns unevaluated.  However, with help it can provide a solution.  First, note that pde is separable:
pde /. y -> Function[{x, t}, f[x] g[t]];
(Cancel[#/(f[x] g[t])] & /@ (%[[1]])) == 0
(* -1 - (x f'[x])/f[x] + g]'[t]/g[t] - f^''[x]/f[x] == 0 *)

Then, the substitution
solf = DSolve[% /. g'[t]/g[t] -> -c, f[x], x] // Flatten;
solg = (DSolve[g'[t]/g[t] == -c, g[t], t] // Flatten) /. C[1] -> 1;
sol = f[x] g[t] /. solf /. solg
(* E^(-c t) (E^(-(x^2/2)) C[1]  HermiteH[c, x/Sqrt[2]] + 
   E^(-(x^2/2)) C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[-(c/2), 1/2, x^2/2]) *)

as can be verified by
FullSimplify[pde /. y -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@sol]]
(* True *)

Hypergeometric1F1[-(c/2), 1/2, x^2/2]) is symmetric about x = 0, whereas  HermiteH[c, x/Sqrt[2]] is not.  So, set C[1] -> 0`.
 solsym = sol /. C[1] -> 0

It so happens that solsym with C[2] -> 1//Sqrt[2 Pi] and c -> 0 exactly satisfies the initial condition specified in the question.
solsym /. C[2] -> 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] /. c -> 0
(* E^(-(x^2/2))/Sqrt[2 Pi] *)

independent of time.  More generally, solutions with other symmetric initial conditions will evolve in time to E^(-(x^2/2)) multiplied by a constant.

Thanks for the detailed answer, and the cool method! Well, first thing I'm going to do now, is switch to 14.0.

If you could add a few more explanations about your derivation, that would be wonderful.
Using 14.0, Trial version for Windows, I am getting errors:
(1) Running your first two lines yields
False + (0 == -((x Derivative[1][f][x])/f[x])) + (0 ==
Derivative[1][g][t]/g[t]) + (0 == -((f^[Prime][Prime])[x]/f[x]))
(2) Running the next lines, with the solf and solg, leads to a series of error messages too long for this comment, but no solution.
Can you help figure out what is still going wrong?
Thanks!

@user1611107 I miscopied the second and last lines of code, now corrected.  Sorry.

Works perfect.. Thanks
